# JPA - Join another entity by EmbeddedId with 2 columns

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence, one-to-one

Basically. I have a ProductEntity, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product", schema = "shop")
     public class ShopProductEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductEntityId id;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "product_category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = "product_language_id")
    private int languageId;

    // TODO: Get category by categoryId and languageId. 
    private CategoryEntity category;
```

I have another CategoryIdentity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category", schema = "shop")
public class CategoryEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CategoryEntityId id;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "category_url")
    private String url;
```

It has an EmbeddedId like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class CategoryEntityId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = "language_id", nullable = false)
    private int languageId;

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public int getLanguageId() {
        return languageId;
    }
```

Now, every product has a category. Categories are unique by their id and language. The shop connects to a category by both the categoryId and languageId columns. How do I add the CategoryEntity to my ProductEntity so I can use the category's url value for my product?

I tried adding this to ShopProductEntity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="categoryId"),
        @JoinColumn(name="languageId", referencedColumnName="languageId"),
})
private CategoryEntity category;
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. Is `@ManyToOne ShopProductEntity.category` not working?

Comment: I updated the original. As of now I want the category to be connected to every product. So I guess it should be ManyToOne since once category can have multiple products? And it needs to look so ShopProductEntity.id.languageId = CategoryEntity.id.languageId && ShopProductEntity.categoryId = CategoryEntity.id.categoryId.

Comment: `ShopProductEntity.id.languageId = CategoryEntity.id.languageId` is unenforceable using JPA. If categories have languages, and every product has a category, then `ShopProductEntity.languageId` is redundant. You can deduce the language based on the associated category

Comment: Categories are only unique by both languageId and categoryId (therefore the embeddedId). There are 3 categories with the same categoryId and 3 different languageIds.

Comment: I fail to see how that relates to my previous comment. Out of those three categories with different `languageId`s, a particular `Product` can still only belong to one

Comment: But, the system doesn't know which one just by categoryId because it isn't unique. Therefore it can't join product and category because there are multiple categories with the same categoryId.

Comment: I understand that. For the same reason, `languageId` is redundant in `ShopProductEntity`. In order to get the `ShopProductEntity`'s language, you should be using `shopProduct.getCategory().getId().getLanguageId()`. Also, the referenced column names are wrong in the `@ManyToOne` mapping - they should be `category_id` and `language_id` (and not `categoryId`, `language_id`)